# Is it possible to prove that there exists no arithmetic sequence which consists only of primes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

This is a question from the textbook 'Cambridge Senior Mathematics for Queensland', Exercise 4B.

> (25) Show that there is no infinite arithmetic sequence whose terms are all prime numbers.

While the fact that there is no known pattern in [prime gaps](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Prime_gap) is enough to prove that an arbitrarily long arithmetic sequence consisting only of primes could exist, I am not sure that it is enough to prove that an infinite arithmetic sequence. Conversely, I can find no proven evidence that there does not exist an infinitely long arithmetic sequence whose terms are all prime numbers (though, perhaps I am looking in the wrong places).

Comment: I don't know how I missed that question. Nevertheless, I would like to keep this question open as the answer given by @D_S is much more elementary than the answers given in that question.

Answer (score 11):

Given any arithmetic sequence $$n, n+k, n+2k, ...$$ you will eventually get to the term $n + nk$, which is not prime.

Edit: my answer does not cover the case $n =1$.  In this case, I still claim there is a composite number in the sequence

$$1, 1+k, 1+2k, ...$$

Let $p$ be any prime number which is bigger than $k$.  Since $k$ and $p$ are relatively prime, there exist infinitely many positive integers $a$ such that $ak \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.  Thus infinitely many terms $1+ak$ in the arithmetic sequence are properly divisible by $p$ and hence not prime.

Comment: ... Yeah, that should have been obvious. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This answer would do well with a bit of polishing. What if $n=1$? (Not that I think it isn't obvious how to plug this gap, but I feel it should be done for completeness.)

Comment: What if $k = 0$ and $n$ is prime?

Comment: @JosephChung in that case, you do not have an arithmetic sequence at all, only a single number.

Comment: @StinkingBishop good point, I have edited.

Comment: It is a trivial arithmetic sequence, but it is still an arithmetic sequence. A teacher should probably thank the student the student for the contribution and ask that the question be answered for non-constant sequences.

Comment: Not a teacher, just a guy who likes answering interesting questions.  And everyone who isn't this guy (https://imgur.com/a/P10zWP4 ) thinks of arithmetic sequences as having infinitely many terms.

Comment: An alternate way to deal with the $n=1$ case is just to consider $1+(k+2)k = (k+1)^2$. One way to see how one could derive similar expressions is to rewrite the $n$th term as $1+k+k(n-1)$. This gives rise to the general case of $n+(n+k+1)k = (n+k)(k+1)$.

Comment: @D_S yes, but do the infinitely many terms have to be unique?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but Dirichlet's theorem says that if $(a,b)=1$ then the arithmetic progression $\{an+b\}, n\in\mathbb{N}$ contains infinitely many primes.